# React Native : What is the way to solve the problem of close keyboard in every typing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, android-softkeyboard

What is the way to solve the problem that with each typing of the keyboard it just closes ..
Every time you press a button on the keyboard, it closes and it is not clear why.
I would be happy to help with this problem.

**This is the function**

```
const onChangeInput = (index, value) => {
    if (isNumeric(value)) {
      const newMeasurements = [...inputMeasurement];
      newMeasurements[index] = value;
      setInputMeasurement(newMeasurements);
      updateInputText(UPDATE_TYPE.MEASUREMENT, newMeasurements);
    } else {
      console.log(index, 'onChangeInput is NOT a valid decimal:', value);
      Toast.show({ text1: 'NUMBERS ONLY' });
      return;
    }
  };
```

**This is the TextInput**

```
<TextInput
            style={styles.ParamTextInput}
            blurOnSubmit={true}
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
            keyboardType="number-pad"
            maxLength={6}
            placeholder="input.."
            onChangeText={(text) => onChangeInput(index, text)}
            value={inputMeasurement[index]}
            onBlur={() => console.log('onBlur for index:', index)}
          />
```

Comment: what did updateInputText(UPDATE_TYPE.MEASUREMENT, newMeasurements) do? what about delete this line?

Comment: its not working..i delete it but it still make the problem